# Modelagem de Models 1 to n

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelagem

estou modelando um sistema para Academias.
Criei 2 models,

**Modalidade**

```
 public class Modalidade
    {
        [Key]
        public int ModalidadeId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
        [ForeignKey("ModalidadeId")]
        public virtual Horario Horarios { get; set; }
}
```

**Horario**

```
 public class Horario
    {
        [Key]
        public int HorarioId { get; set; }


        public int ModalidadeId { get; set; }


        public byte HoraInicial { get; set; }

        public byte HoraFinal { get; set; }


        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
        public virtual ICollection<Modalidade> Modalidade { get; set; }
    }
```

Eu resumi, porém penso no horário colocar os dias da semana (seg, ter, quar, etc) e também o ProfessorId, visto que uma única modalidade pode ter professores diferentes, ex: Segunda, modalidade = Karate, sala=1 professor=1, Quarta, Modalidade = Karate, sala=2, professor=2;

Resumo: Posso ter vários horários para 1 única modalidade.

Minha dúvida: Ao criar primeiro a modalidade, daria erro no Banco de dados, pq a tabela Horario precisa do ModalidadeId, então criar primeiro o horario (estranho) eu ainda nem saberia qual o Id?

Tentei executar e claro que deu erro:

```
    var mod = new Modalidade
    {
        Nome = @"TKD",
        DataCadastro = DateTime.Now,
        Excluido=false
    };
    var hor = new Horario
    {
        HoraFinal = 9,
        HoraInicial = 8,
        ModalidadeId = mod.ModalidadeId
    };
    db.Modalidades.Add(mod);
    db.Horarios.Add(hor);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

> Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'Arena.Models.Modalidade'
>   no tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[Arena.Models.Modalidade]'.

Comment: Eu faria muitos para muitos. porque? uma modalidade por ter vários horários e um horário pode estar em varias modalidade?

Comment: tem fundamento, porém pensei depois em colocar o ProfessorId vinculado ao Horario.
Pois 1 modalidade posso ter vários professores. Dai como seria?

Comment: Ai vai complicando, tem que pensar primeiro no design das tabelas para depois refletir no modelo de classes. Tem que analisar professor, modalidade e horário, porque professor não pode chocar os horários.

Comment: preciso de um help..rs vamos tentar no meu caso acima, o pq do erro?

Comment: Bom vou comentar nisso que estou vendo o relacionamento está invertido, se for 1 para muitos 1 modalidade tem diversos horários e um horário pertence a uma modalidade ( ai que está, também está errado deveria ser muitos para muitos) mas, no modelo atual está invertido.

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem sua dúvida. Mas se você tivesse um cadastro para Sala, Professor, Modalidade e Horario e, com isso, criar uma tabela associativa `SalaProfessorModalidadeHorario` e assim você teria os cadastros distintos e uma tabela associativa para fazer o que deseja. Sem falar que seria fácil retirar os relatórios dessa forma.

Comment: Agora, isso de criar um Model apenas para os Horários pode lhe causar problema, pois se editar o horário de um irá editar de todos os demais.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dorathoto vendo sua ideia de ter uma entidade `Horario`, com inicio e fim acredito que o seu principal problema é que a `Modalidade` que tem uma `ICollection` de horários e não ao contrário como você mapeou.

Seguindo sua ideia, eu mapiei 4 entidades `Modalidade`, `Professor`, `Sala` e `Horario`, sendo essa última uma entidade associativa entre as outras 3.

Ficando da seguinte forma o meu exemplo

```
public class Modalidade
{
    [Key]
    public int ModalidadeId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    // modalidade tem horários
    public ICollection<Horario> Horarios { get; set; }
}

public class Professor
{
    [Key]
    public int ProfessorId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    // Professor tem horários
    public ICollection<Horario> Horarios { get; set; }
}

public class Sala
{
    public int SalaId { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    //Sala tem horários
    public ICollection<Horario> Horarios { get; set; }
}

public class Horario
{
    [Key]
    public int ModalidadeProfessorSalaHorarioId { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataHoraInicio { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataHoraFim { get; set; }

    public int ModalidadeId { get; set; }

    public int ProfessorId { get; set; }

    public int SalaId { get; set; }

    //Horário tem Modalidade
    public virtual Modalidade Modalidade { get; set; }

    //Horário tem professor
    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }

    //Horário tem Sala
    public virtual Sala Sala { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Dessa forma que ficou o meu modelo ER]

> Resumo: Posso ter vários horários para 1 única modalidade.

Da forma como mapiei isso estaria contemplado.
Claro que seria necessário alguns verificações para evitar que a mesma sala seja ocupada mais de uma vez no mesmo intervalo de horários. Mesma verificação teria que ser feita para o professor.

> Minha dúvida: Ao criar primeiro a modalidade, daria erro no Banco de
>   dados, pq a tabela Horario precisa do ModalidadeId, então criar
>   primeiro o horario (estranho) eu ainda nem saberia qual o Id?

Essa sua duvida parte do problema do seu mapeamento, de ter uma lista de horários na modalidade e não a entidade `Horario` ter uma lista de modalidades.

Answer (score 3):

Não seria o caso de ter a modelagem abaixo?

Pensando OO, temos um objeto professor, um horário e um modalidade.

Onde eles se encontram? Na minha opinião na Aula.

Cada aula é única na semana e ela tem 1 Professor, 1 horário e 1 modalidade.

Ex:

```
Professor joao = new Professor {Nome = "João" };
Horario seg8as9 = new Horario {DiaDaSemana="Seg", HoraInicial=8, HoraFinal=9};
Modalidade tkd = new Modalidade {Nome="TKD"};

Aula aulaTKDSeg8as9ProfJoao = new Aula {Professor=joao, Horario=seg8as9, Modalidade=tkd};

db.Professor.Add(joao)
db.Horarios.Add(seg8as9);
db.Modalidades.Add(tkd);
db.Aulas.Add(aulaTKDSeg8as9ProfJoao);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Fiz o código de cabeça, não testei então é possível que ajustes sejam necessários, foi apenas para dar uma ideia.

```
public class Professor {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
}

public class Horario {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string DiaDaSemana {get; set;}
    public byte HoraInicial {get; set;}
    public byte HoraFinal {get; set;}
}

public class Modalidade {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
}


public class Aula {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int ProfessorId {get; set;}

    public int HorarioId {get; set;}

    public int ModalidadeId {get; set;}

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual Horario Horario { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute]
    public virtual Modalidade Modalidade { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Caso minha solução atenda sua necessidade, peço a gentileza de marcá-la como solução aceitável (check verde) isso melhora minha reputação ;)

Comment: Qual o sentido de separar aulas e horários?

Comment: Pelo que havia entendido num mesmo horário pode haver várias Aulas.
Ex: Seg. 08:00 - 09:00 - Judo. Seg. 08:00 - 09:00 - Karate. Seg. 08:00 - 09:00 - Zumba.

Comment: O problema é que isso só permite que as aulas tenham as durações definidas. Se uma aula começa 9h30 e acaba 11h?

Comment: Dai cria-se um Horário para isso e seta esse horário na aula.

Comment: Por fim, qual o ganho prático dessa abordagem? O que se agrega ao sistema tendo essa separação?

Comment: A explicação está na minha resposta.

Comment: Você não precisa concordar com a abordagem, é apenas uma ideia.