# Guardando multiplos valores de uma enum no banco de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelagem, enums

Gostaria de poder guardar várias opções de uma enum (dia da semana) algo como
1,3,5 (segunda, quarta, sexta)

[Conforme modelagem descrita aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/154283/modelagem-de-models-1-to-n)

Criei uma model

```
public class Horario
{
[Key]
public int ModalidadeProfessorSalaHorarioId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public DiaDaSemana DiaDaSemana { get; set; }
}
```

Esse dia da semana é um enum

```
 [Flags]
    public enum DiaDaSemana
    {
        Domingo=0,
        Segunda=1,
        Terça=2,
        Quarta=3,
        Quinta=4,
        Sexta=5,
        Sábado=6
    }
```

Porém ao dar o migrations ele cria como int

Na view o Insert estou fazendo

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.DiaDaSemana, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "true"  })
```

Estou pensando em criar o campo como string, criar uma viewmodel mandar o campo como string e o enum, e dai na controller fazer a união, não sei se isso é uma gambiarra, mas acho que funcionaria.

OBS: O campo `[flag]` do enum junto com o `@Html.EnumDropDownListFor` não roda, preciso desabilitar o flag

> ```
> O tipo de retorno 'Enums.DiaDaSemana' não tem suporte. O tipo não deve ter um atributo 'Flags'.
> Nome do parâmetro: expression
> ```

[Tentei utilizar essa solução mais sem sucesso.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264927/model-bind-list-of-enum-flags)

Comment: Qual a necessidade de guardar no banco?

Comment: preciso guardar os dias da semana no banco!

Comment: Isso eu entendi, estou perguntando o motivo.

Comment: coloquei o link da modelagem

Comment: Uma enum é apenas um Apelido para uma constante de mapeamento  ou id. Internamente é convertido para o tipo adequado. Trate como tal, receba do banco o int e faça o cast. Deve-se ter cuidado com isso: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifique suas flags para que elas correspondam a bits, permitindo assim operações booleanas:

```
[Flags]
public enum DiaDaSemana
{
    Domingo = 1, // 0x00000001
    Segunda = 2, // 0x00000010
    Terca = 4,   // 0x00000100
    Quarta = 8,  // 0x00001000
    Quinta = 16, // 0x00010000
    Sexta = 32,  // 0x00100000
    Sabado = 64  // 0x01000000
}
```

Assim combinações de datas podem ser expressas somando os valores:

```
var QuintaSextaESabado = DiaDaSemana.Quinta + DiaDaSemana.Sexta + DiaDaSemana.Sabado;
//  QuintaSextaESabado = 112 decimal, 0x01110000 binario
```

Para verificar se um dado dia está presente em um dado valor, utilize um operador booleano AND:

```
var temSexta = QuintaSextaESabado && DiaDaSemana.Sexta;
```

> Dica: não utilize diacríticos (acentos, cedilha, etc.) em objetos. Note como modifiquei as entradas em seu enum para `Terca` e `Sabado`.

Comment: e depois se eu tiver o 112 em decimal consigo saber quais dias da semana eram? como ele fará isso?

Comment: @Dorathoto utilizando o último exemplo da resposta; realize uma operação AND entre os itens do `enum` e o valor armazenado.